# Build of opencv4 for c++ using cmake failing after upgrading to macOS Catalina

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, cmake, macos-catalina

hi I am trying to build opencv4 from source using cmake (following https://thecodinginterface.com/blog/opencv-cpp-vscode/). I updated my macOS to 10.15 and installed the latest xcode. I git cloned repositories and make a build directory as below and I then try to configure cmake:

```
$ mkdir opencv
$ cd opencv
$ git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
$ cd opencv
$ git checkout tags/4.2.0
$ cd ..
$ git clone https://github.com/opencv/
$ cd opencv_contrib 
$ git checkout tags/4.2.0
$ cd ..


$ cd build_opencv
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install \
      -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
      -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules \
      -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ../opencv
```

I get the below errors and it seems that it's trying to find this non-existent path:

"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework"

I have updated my mac version to 10.15 but it seems to be searching for a path under MacOSX10.14. I've looked online but I can't seem to find any suggestions?

```
CMake Error in /usr/local/include/opencv/build_opencv/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:
  Imported target "VTK::RenderingOpenGL2" includes non-existent path

    "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework"

  in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.  Possible reasons include:

  * The path was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
  provide.



CMake Error in /usr/local/include/opencv/build_opencv/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:
  Imported target "VTK::RenderingOpenGL2" includes non-existent path

    "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework"

  in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.  Possible reasons include:

  * The path was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
  provide.



CMake Error in /usr/local/include/opencv/build_opencv/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:
  Imported target "VTK::RenderingOpenGL2" includes non-existent path

    "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework"

  in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.  Possible reasons include:

  * The path was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
  provide.



CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVDetectVTK.cmake:73 (try_compile):
  Failed to generate test project build system.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:767 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Installing XCode and installing the XCode CLT are two different tasks. Did you do both? Did you have this built before upgrading to Catalina? If so, you need to get rid of your old install folder and start from scratch. Did you check the requirementsof openCV and whatit supports?

Comment: I installed Xcode and XCode CLT after I upgraded to Catalina. I also checked the requirements and have installed the necessary prerequisites. I'm just not sure why it's still looking for a path under macOS10.14? Do you mean remove the install folder of opencv and start again?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install

> Command Line Tools for XCode 12

from the [apple developer tools downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?&name=for%20Xcode).

It used to work that you could execute `xcode-select --install` and it would do it for you, however, there is now an error occurring where it says that it cannot find the package or something like that. Therefore, this approach has to be taken.